# How to put css and javascript in a common library/ project

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

We have a number of asp and asp mvc web apps that need to share static resources. I'd like to be able to put these in a common project that can be shared across sites but I'm unsure how to do this? I understand we could use a CDN, but would prefer a common project approach. Any examples would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: asp = asp.net or asp classic?

Comment: oops. asp.net - thanks Anthony!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are really two (or three) issues here, and resolving the problem is not as simple as it should be.

The first issue is having the shared resources available at runtime - for that, putting the resources on a CDN may work, but you're probably going to need to reference these during design, as well as include them in your version control system.

The second is sharing common resources across ASP.Net Projects & Solutions, and sadly the ability to do this will depend on the third item, your source control system.

If you're using VSS, well, you have my sympathies, and you're stuck for now.  It's time to upgrade anyways.

Other version control systems (including TFS) don't have quite the same inflexible link between projects & solutions and the repository.  You should be able to have multiple solutions & projects overlapping, something along the lines of:

```
 Root
   Web\
      App1\
      App2\
      SharedResources\
   Class1\
   Class2\
   etc
```

You can have multiple Web app projects - one can reference Web\App1 and resources in Web\SharedResources, another Web\App2 and overlapping resources in Web\SharedResources, and then have multiple solutions tied to a single source control repository.  Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to do this and have the resources and apps in separate structures.

Depending on where you want to keep your .sln and .proj files, you may have to manually edit them to update the paths - Visual Studio won't really like creating this type of overlapping structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own CDN by hosting those static files in a separate web server.